# Creating a Round Image in TableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am getting a list of images from Parse and I am trying to display them all as a circle even though the image in Parse is a square. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I use this code:

```
cell1.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = cell1.imageView!.frame.size.height / 2
cell1.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
```

Here is what appears now: [image]

Why are the images not round?

Comment: what do you mean you can't get the image? you want to edit the image view, and you're setting an image into it somehow

Comment: @Wain Please check out my updated question!

Comment: Show how the cell is registered, dequeued and the image is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAKE SURE you set the masksToBounds to true immediately after you manipulate the corner radius.:

```
cell.cellImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

This is the last step you're missing.

Comment: Hi Jay, please check out my updated question! I am not using a custom tableView cell. I've tried masksToBounds and clipsToBounds and they both don't work.

Comment: hey @DanL i noticed in your code, between the imageView and the "clipToBounds" doesn't have layer, try that? also if that doesn't work i think your best bet is to create a custom cell.

Comment: Thanks, @Jay. I ended up creating a custom cell because not off of the pictures in Parse will be the same exact size or even a square. I was able to do a custom cell with an image view and everything works perfectly!